# How do I powerfully discretize a PDE?

Tags: julia, libraries, numerical-methods, differential-equations

The problem I'm trying to solve is this PDE,
[image]

I wrote the buck of the solver as follows (mostly based on the **Euler Explicit**):

```
for n in 2:N-1
    wl[n]= w[n] + Δx*v[n]
    ϕl[n]= ϕ[n] + Δx*ρ[n] 
    ρl[n] = ρ[n] - (Δt/Δx)*(dif_nt(ρ,n)*v[n]) + (Δt)*w[n]*ρ[n]
    vl[n] = v[n] - (Δt/Δx)*(v[n]*w[n]) + (μ*Δt/(ρ[n]*Δx))*(dif_nt(w,n)) + (c₀^2*Δt/ρ[n]*Δx)*(dif_nt(ρ,n)) + (Δt/τ)*(V(ρ[n])-v[n])
end
```

In which the dif_nt is simply the forward distance u[n+1] - u[n] for a variable. *nt* stands for no-time.

```
function dif_nt(v, n)
    return v[n+1] - v[n]
end
```

How could I find a good approximation to (pl[n],vl[n],ϕ[n],wl[n]), e.i., these are the next-step values in time?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for has been solved in matlab for a long time and it's called [pdepe](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html) .  If you're just looking for an answer, I'd suggest just switching to this more robust package if you can.

Unfortunately the Julia ecosystems is not as developed as the Matlab ecosystem when it comes to PDE's.  The survey found in [this repo](https://github.com/JuliaPDE/SurveyofPDEPackages) might be of use to you.  There are some implementation of finite difference techniques [in this repo](https://github.com/DanPSilva/Partial-Differential-Equations).